# Pass variables from shell script to SQL

Tags: sql, shell

### I have an SQL statement file 1.sql:

```
set pages 0
set head off
set feed off

select $1 from
(
       select $1 from user_tab_partitions
        where table_name = 'test'
            order by partition_position desc
        )
        where rownum = 1;
```

---

and I would like to execute the same SQL statement in a shell script, 1.sh:

---

```
#!/bin/ksh


username="test"
passwrd="testpass"
partition_name=$1
partition_position=$2

PARTNAME=`sqlplus -s $username/$passwrd << EOT
@1.sql $1
exit
EOT`

echo $PARTNAME

PARTPOS=`sqlplus -s $username/$passwrd << EOT
@1.sql $2
exit
EOT`

echo $PARTPOS
```

--

So, basically what I'm doing is executing the same SQL but with different inputs. 
and I don't know how to pass these variables from SHELL script to the SQL script.

What should I change in my code???!!

Thanks for your time!
/Hesi

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your SQL Script from $1 to &1.  The $1 will on work if you imbed the SQL into the actual script here doc.

```
set pages 0
set head off
set feed off

select &1 from
(
       select &1 from user_tab_partitions
        where table_name = 'test'
            order by partition_position desc
        )
        where rownum = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks! It's getting much better now but I get this error:    Enter value for 1: old 1: select &1 from new 1: select exit from Enter value for 1: SP2-0546: User requested Interrupt or EOF detected.

Comment: What's the problem with the Shell script that calls this SQL?!!

Comment: I tested it on my machine and it works for syntax.  I am not sure why you are attempting to create an in line view to only pull up the same column name.